# my express POST request returns empty body

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to carry out a POST request using body-parser as follows:

```
var app = require('express')();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var port = 1200;

console.log('Server is up at ' + port);

app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/*+json' }));

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    console.log('app.use entered...');
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
});

app.get('/msgboard', function(req, res) {
    console.log('app.get entered...');
    res.json(messages);
});

app.post('/message', function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
    res.sendStatus(200);
});

app.listen(port);
```

but just {} is consoled. If I don't specify a type for body-parser, it returns Syntax Error.

**Here's what I send:**
[image]

Comment: Try to wrap properties name within `""` . For instance, `"messageText"`. That's the json format.

Comment: https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ - your JSON is not valid. Above comment explains why.

Comment: Thank's guys, that really helped out!